# Should I have to refresh the page to view answers?

Tags: support, live-refresh, information-display

Should I have to refresh the Stack page to view answers or are the answers loaded automatically by pull mechanism such as "Ajax"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Stack Overflow, they are loaded automatically for any registered with >50 reps.

For all other Stack Exchange sites, answers are loaded automatically for all the users, even anonymous.

All the above applies not only to answers, but also to all the kinds of real-time updates.

Comment: Why are the answers only auto-loaded for any registered guy with over 50 rep? Why can't a guy with 1 rep have that privilege?

Comment: @Pyth That's done because of very high traffic.